# Print AngularJS Paginated Values

Tags: angularjs

I need to print all the values in a paginated ng-repeat.

I've tried this function but it just prints everything on the screen and doesn't print the paginated values past page 1.  I also tried creating a separate html file just for printing but I don't know how to pass the data to the separate page.

```
        function printResults(id) {
        var contents = $("#" + id).html();

        if ($("#printDiv").length == 0) {
            var printDiv = null;
            printDiv = document.createElement('div');
            printDiv.setAttribute('id', 'printDiv');
            printDiv.setAttribute('class', 'printable');
            $(printDiv).appendTo('body');
        }

        $("#printDiv").html(contents);

        window.print();

        $("#printDiv").remove();

    }
```

The div I'm trying to print:

```
        <div id="printMe" class="provider" ng-repeat="provider in vm.filteredProviders">
        <p class="provider-header">{{provider.header}}</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <p>{{provider.providerGroupName}}</p>
                <p>{{provider.city}}, {{provider.state}} {{provider.zipCode}}</p>
                <p>{{provider.phone}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <p><strong>Specialties</strong></p>
                <p>
                    <span ng-repeat="specialty in provider.specialties">
                        {{specialty}}
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <p><strong>Language(s):</strong></p>
                <p>
                    <span ng-repeat="language in provider.languages">
                        {{language}}
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 pull-right">
                <p><strong>Network</strong></p>
                <p>{{provider.providerNetwork}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 pull-left">
                <p><strong>Accepting New Patients</strong></p>
                <p>{{provider.acceptingNewPatients ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
    </div>

    <ul class="non-printable" uib-pagination total-items="vm.totalItems" items-per-page="vm.itemsPerPage"
        max-size="vm.maxSize" force-ellipses="true" boundary-link-numbers="true" ng-disabled="vm.isPrinting"
        ng-model="vm.currentPage" ng-change="vm.pageChanged()" ng-show="vm.providers.length > 0">
    </ul>
```

Comment: Can Please get that value in variable and print out when print page at use visible print related class.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the variable vm.filteredProviders?

Comment: Now your data are displaying pagination wise right but  In your  Print Display all data or not ? I am confused

Comment: If I try to use a separate html page just for printing I don't know how to pass the data from my current page which is showing the paginated results, if I try to print the page that's showing the pagination I don't know how to first remove the pagination, I'm really not sure about the best approach for this, my end goal is to be able to click a button and have all of my paginated results open in a print window without being paginated, sorry if I'm not explaining myself very well.

Comment: Firstly you need to give first pagination portion in one div and also give that div have class="hidden-print". So, Pagination do not print on your print

Comment: you mean your paginated Result for particular page index ?

Comment: no, I mean print all of the pages, so I currently have 20 results per page and a total of 5 pages, I want to print all 100 results